# How can I modify my code for the desired format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

```
def rle_encode(data):
    encoding = ''
    prev_char = ''
    count = 1

    if not data: return ''

    for char in data:
        # If the prev and current characters
        # don't match...
        if char != prev_char:
            # ...then add the count and character
            # to our encoding
            if prev_char:
                encoding += str(count) + prev_char
            count = 1
            prev_char = char
        else:
            # Or increment our counter
            # if the characters do match
            count += 1
    else:
        # Finish off the encoding
        encoding += str(count) + prev_char
        return encoding

encoded_val = rle_encode(“aaaaBBbbCooa”)
print(encoded_val)
```

For the above string, I am getting the output as : "4a2B2b1C2o1a"

But the expected output is :"4a2B2bC2oa"

That means that for the single character I dont need to put ist number, only the character.

It would be really great if someone tell me where to make changes in the code to get the expected format of output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `itertools.groupby`. If the length of the group is greater than 1 then prepend the count, otherwise just add the character itself.

```
from itertools import groupby

def rle_encode(data):
    out = ''
    for key, group in groupby(data):
        run = len(list(group))
        if run > 1:
            out += str(run) + key
        else:
            out += key
    return out
```

Example

```
>>> rle_encode("aaaaBBbbCooa")
'4a2B2bC2oa'
```

Comment: Like your answer. Python provides a lot of built-in libraries that are very convenient. `itertools` is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your fixed code.

```py
def rle_encode(data):
    encoding = ''
    prev_char = ''
    count = 1

    if not data: return ''

    for char in data:
        # If the prev and current characters
        # don't match...
        if char != prev_char:
            # ...then add the count and character
            # to our encoding
            if prev_char:
                if count > 1:
                    encoding += str(count) + prev_char
                else:
                    encoding += prev_char
            count = 1
            prev_char = char
        else:
            # Or increment our counter
            # if the characters do match
            count += 1
    else:
        # Finish off the encoding
        if count > 1:
            encoding += str(count) + prev_char
        else:
            encoding += prev_char
        return encoding
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, @Cory's solution is better and it even simplified your function a lot. But if you still want your solution, I think it is as easy as removing the '1's

```
def rle_encode(data):
    encoding = ''
    prev_char = ''
    count = 1

    if not data: return ''

    for char in data:
        # If the prev and current characters
        # don't match...
        if char != prev_char:
            # ...then add the count and character
            # to our encoding
            if prev_char:
                encoding += str(count) + prev_char
            count = 1
            prev_char = char
        else:
            # Or increment our counter
            # if the characters do match
            count += 1
    # Finish off the encoding
    encoding += str(count) + prev_char
    return encoding.replace('1', '')

encoded_val = rle_encode('aaaaBBbbCooa')
print(encoded_val)
```

BTW, I don't think your last "else" is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def rle_encode(data):
    encoding = ''
    prev_char = ''
    count = 1

    if not data: return ''

    for char in data:
        # If the prev and current characters
        # don't match...
        print(char," ", count)
        if char != prev_char:
            # ...then add the count and character
            # to our encoding
            if prev_char:
                if count != 1:
                    encoding += str(count) + prev_char
                else:
                    encoding += prev_char

            count = 1
            prev_char = char
        else:
            # Or increment our counter
            # if the characters do match
            count += 1
    else:
        # Finish off the encoding
        if count != 1:
            encoding += str(count) + prev_char
        else:
            encoding += prev_char
        return encoding

encoded_val = rle_encode('aaaaBBbbCooa')
print(encoded_val)


Hope this will help you.
```